# Installing watchOS 3.1

Tags: apple-watch, beta, watchos-3

I am trying to install watchOS 3.1 on my Watch so to have it in tune with the beta version on my iPhone. I downloaded the Configuration Profile to automatically download updates but I have no cue about how to install it on my watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page answers my question:

> https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/install-watchos-beta/